# Python3: creating error for input of negative

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

Taking an intro course and need to create an over/under guessing game. I want to fine-tune my user inputs by creating an error if someone inputs a negative or non-integer. I have the non-integer error reporting correctly, and the negative loops back correctly, but the negative will not print my error message.

```
#Number of plays
def get_plays(msg):
    while True:
        try:
            x = (int(input(msg)))

        except ValueError:
            print ("Integer numbers only please.")
        except:
            if x <=0:
                print ("Positive numbers only please.")

i = get_plays("\nHow many times would you like to play?")
print ("The game will play " +str(i)+" times.")
```

Separately, if I wanted to use a similar setup to produce an error for any negative non-integer number between 1 and 20, how would this look?

Comment: For what input exactly do you think `except:` block will be executed?

Comment: Move the `if` statement to the `try` part maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
def get_plays(msg):
    while True:
        try:
            x = (int(input(msg)))
            if x <=0:
                print("Positive numbers only please.")
                continue
            if x not in range(20):
                print("Enter a number between 1 - 20.")
                continue
            return x
        except ValueError:
            print("Integer numbers only please.")
```

It will accept only positive numbers between 1 to 20

Comment: yup, that's it for the second part! was right in line with what i was thinking, just spent too many hours looking at the code to see my mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this section

```
except:
    if x <=0:
```

Empty `except` clauses trigger on any error that hasn't been caught yet, but negative numbers don't trigger an exception. You want something like this instead. Notice that in the `try` clause we can just proceed as if `x` is an int already, because we can assume that no `ValueError` was thrown.

```
def get_plays(msg):
    while True:
        try:
            x = (int(input(msg)))
            if x <=0:
                print ("Positive numbers only please.")
            else:
                return x

        except ValueError:
            print ("Integer numbers only please.")
```

Comment: yup, that's what i was looking at/for! was right in line with what i was thinking, just spent too many hours looking at the code to see my mistake. Thanks!